# the addition of the word in PHP

Tags: php

why there is the addition of the word "Hello" when I only write one ??

The few pieces of script :

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <?php
      $s = "SELECT * FROM `admin`";
      $sql = mysqli_query($link,$s);
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
     ?>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Hallo <b><?php echo $row[0]; ?></b></a></li>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

so result :

[image]

Comment: You are looping over all records in the admin table, if there are 2 rows, it will loop twice, if one, once. Seeing the result, it seems you have 2 records.

Answer (score 1):

We can divide your code snippet in 3 parts:

1. Start the `<div>` of the navbar;
2. Retrieve data from Database;
3. Iterate over the returned data, while filling the `<div>` with new lists and it's first entry, the one with the "Hello" word.

Let's look at a snippet of the 3rd part:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#">Hallo <b><?php echo $row[0]; ?></b></a></li>
```

In the first line you start a list. As you're in a loop, you probably should consider to put this code outside of the `while` loop.

In the second line, you're printing the first column of each row, after the "Hello" word, in the `<li>` item list.
As you have 2 rows in the `admin` table, you print this twice, with the first row having a null or empty string value on the first column, and the second row has admin on the same first column.